# Is there a memory leak in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, memory

I have updated to macOS Montery Beta 12.0 (21A5294g) and after some time the macOS always runs out of memory and I get the "Your system has run out of memory" window. The screenshot below is taken about 20 after booting. The memory is almost used completely (27,90 GB of 32,00 GB). Also you can see the memory in swap at 38,86 GB. The swapped memory is constantly increasing, every minute 2 GB or so.

My question is less how to fix the issue (although this would also be nice to know). But more, how I find out what the memory is using, because as you can see the memory used by the applications doesn't add up to 27 GB. **I also have "View all processes" enabled in the "view" tab.**

What is using all that memory? The os? Why doesn't it show what is using that memory?

**Edit:**
I changed the screenshot, to enable the real Memory column, but still the memory doesn't add up.

[image]

Comment: It is a beta - exp[ect there to be problems - It is why Apple wants you to test it.

Comment: I do expect that, but I don't understand where all the ram is used.

Comment: Add the "Real Memory" column to the display. (right-click on the column header.) Make sure you report the issue to Apple.

Comment: @benwiggy in addition to adding the real memory column, OP needs to enable "Show All Processes" to see everything that's using memory.

Comment: @At0mic Check the bold part of the question. I already did that.

Comment: @benwiggy I updated the screenshot with the new column, but it's still far from adding up correctly.

Comment: @NiklasRaab Please gather some more information using the Terminal and add them to the question. Specifically run "vm_stat", and then "sudo ps -awxm -o %mem,rss,comm | sort -nr | head".

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, on *the release version* of Monterey. Just as I clicked to reply, the window popped up.

Comment: Also, if I don't close apps quickly enough, it eventually crashes the session and puts me on the login screen. Memory pressure stays in the yellow the whole time. On M1, btw.

Comment: I guess now that it's out of Beta I can go pester Support.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using Chrome. It is a known memory hog (not to mention it's less CPU and energy efficient, less stable, and more prone to security vulnerabilities). Switch to **Safari** for a week and see if your memory issues go away.

(As others have pointed out in comments, bugs are expected in beta releases [and, unfortunately, in final releases] and there may be nothing that you can do to resolve this except wait for an update which has a fix. While Safari definitely uses less memory than Chrome, that alone may not be enough to eliminate your constant memory pressure.)

If this persists without Chrome, we can take the next step and identify which process(es) is/are contributing to the frequent allocations.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, and tip. But how should I find out which process contribute to the frequent allocations, if they don't show up in the screenshot above. The problem is that the memory usage off the processes don't add up to the total memory used. The question was more: How do I find out what process uses all that memory if it doesn't show up in the screenshot.

Comment: @NiklasRaab Let us know when you've tried living on Safari. Root-causing this issue is likely to get involved so simple experiments should be tried first.

Comment: Too bad I don't have enough reputation to down-vote yet.

This happens with every app. "Just stop doing" <integral part of someone's workflow> is generally a bad answer.

Comment: @Paul You're missing the point of my answer. The *first* step is to test whether Chrome is the culprit. If so, *then* we begin the work of determining an underlying cause and possible mitigations. Until the OP actually tries, there is no fruitful investigation to be had. If you are having a similar issue, I invite you to post a new question and then collaborate with the folks here to follow a scientific method.